# Triple id in a Graph Store

Tags: sparql, updates

I am working on SPARQL Update and I was wondering if there is any information with the id of every input triple, i.e. when I insert a triple in the Graph Store does it get a unique id that is retained until the deletion of the triple even if i copy/move/add this triple to another graph?Or every input triple gets an id depending on the graph that contains it?

Comment: While it's possible that some triple stores might do something like this, it's not anything mandated by the SPARQL documentation. The indexing that a triple store performs should make it relatively easy to identify triples by their parts (i.e., the subject, predicate, and object), so checking whether a triple is in a graph or not shouldn't take very long.  Is there a reason that you're looking for this?

Comment: I want to study the provenance of triples. So I need information about the id of a triple in order to model update operations including operators like join, union, projection, filter etc. For example, t1 JOIN t2(first case) or t1 from graph1 JOIN t1 from graph2(second case).

Comment: An interesting use case, to be sure.  You might be a bit better off asking the more provenance-related question on http://answers.semanticweb.com/.  As it stands, this question isn't a great fit for StackOverflow, since it's not about a specific programming problem.  There's lots of research out there on RDF provenance, some going back a few years.  A google search on "RDF provenance" turns up some useful results, and you might get some information about triplestore support from users on http://answers.semanticweb.com/.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "triple id" - triple are values - if you add a triple twice (same SPO) there is only one triple.  It's like numbers - you won't give an id to a number.